# Caveats when using WORM tape

Tags: linux, tape, worm-media

I have been tasked with building a Linux audit retention solution employing write-once (WORM) tapes.  I've read the *st* and *mt* man pages, and understand the *ioctls*.  I readily admit I've never used tape before, so I have a learning curve ahead of me while I play with "normal" tapes using different block sizes, partitions, hardware compression, end-of-file markers, etc, etc...

My conundrum is I cannot, for the life of me, find **anything** about the special circumstances revolving around the usage of WORM tape.  For example, once I close the device for the first time, when a WORM tape is written to, have I exhausted the 1 write? Can I just only write to each block once?  WORM tapes are ~$100/ea, so I really don't want to go around messing with them on the off chance a single write to a single block hoses the entire tape.

I'm using Tandburg LTO-6 drives and HP LTO-6 WORM tapes.

Answer (score 2):

I dont have experience with WORM tapes, but from what I read, you can write to it multiple times.  However, a LTO-3 or later drive will not erase or overwrite data on a WORM cartridge, but will read it.

As I understand it, there is nothing different about the tape medium in a WORM cartridge.  So, older tape drives, not supporting WORM, will be able to read and write to them repeatedly.